# Squashed Pull Request on Github

Tags: git, github

The Scenario:

- Someone makes a pull request to my repo on github
- I pulled the pull request locally to a feature branch
- Rebased the branch and squashed all commits to a single good one
- Merged the feature branch using --no-ff to my master ("Merge pull request #5..") and push to origin

The problem is Github does not recognize these rebase inside the pull request (which should be closed by now), rather obviously because of lost references.

What's the best practice in this case? Especially if i don't want to force the contributor to manually squash his commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood/guessed right, all you're really wanting to do additionally is to tie the squashed merge commit more closely to the Pull Request, and close it automatically.

The way I do this is to add "Closes #5" (Suggestion: as the first line) to the commit description in your Step 3 above. This will result in the PR being closed by the squashed commit and a reference added in the PR by GitHub. Additionally, add a second "Closes #.." if you had an issue in your repository already which this PR closes too. Then both the issue and PR get closed with the same commit and GitHub will reference the squashed commit.

When doing this, I prefer to perform FF merges and hence have only one commit to the mainline per PR. I replace the default "Squashed commit of the following:" commit subject with one that actually describes what it's doing (e.g. "Adds feature to graph usage statistics"), then have the first lines of the commit description be the Closes # lines, and then put the Squashed commit details below that (assuming you want to keep those).